# InitializeUninstall does not run with chained setups

Tags: inno-setup

My problem is InitializeUninstall is failing to run.
I have two setups; SetupA and SetupB.
SetupB is an optional component downloaded by SetupA, and executed by SetupA with an Exec() statement & /silent.
SetupA contains an InitializeUninstall procedure.  SetupB does not.
SetupB successfully appends its install info to unins000.dat, because a subsequent uninstall does remove all the files.
InitializeUninstall runs only if SetupB was *not* part of the install.  When SetupB is part of the install, it does not get executed.  Is there something else I need to do to get it to run?

Comment: After more investigation, it appears SetupB puts something into the unins000.dat file that causes SetupB/InitializeUninstall to run instead of SetupA/InitializeUninstall.  SetupA is a primary application, and SetupB just adds an extra feature.  I need SetupA/InitializeUninstall to run.

Comment: So both installers have the same `AppId`? = they share the `uninst*.dat`?

Comment: That is correct. When SetupB runs, unins000.exe doesn't seem to change, but unins000.dat gets bigger.  Note that the uninstall does remove all files installed by both A and B.  I put Log() statements into InitializeUninstall of both A and B, and only the B got run during the uninstall.  The part about A downloading and running B is not relevant.  The same behavior happens if A and B are both run manually (A first, B second).  Try it yourself with two setups with the same AppID.  In case it is important, my scripts each have CreateUninstallRegKey=no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your architecture is wrong. You cannot use the same `AppId` for different installers.

Instead make Setup A uninstaller run Setup B uninstaller, if found. Of course, each installer has to have a different `AppId`.

Comment: Hmmm.  Is this the recommended approach with secondary setups that merely add more files?  The appending feature works pretty well except it short circuits the running of the uninstall procedures within the first stage installer.  If I understand you correctly, you are saying to change the AppID of SetupB, and add code to SetupA's uninstaller to run SetupB's uninstaller.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean. I do not think that there’s any “recommended” approach. But what you are doing currently simply cannot work.

Comment: Ok.  I'm working on that.  I'm finding that DeinitializeUninstall fires even if InitializeUninstall returns False.  That seems odd.  I use InitializeUninstall to test if Excel is running, and if so to abort the uninstall.  I guess I'll need to set a global variable to tell DeinitializeUninstall about the abort.

Comment: Yes, you need to use a global variable. Or use `CurUninstallStepChanged`.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I've eliminated `DeinitializeUninstall` and instead move what it was doing to  `CurUninstallStepChanged` when usPostUninstall is reached.